# Is it possible to view video/audio information in finder or a similar program

Tags: finder, video, resolution, metadata, encoding

From what I can see finder cannot display codec, resolution, bitrate, basic metadata about batches of video and audio files that would be really helpful.

As there any way to achieve this or a program that can do it in bulk, I searched and did not find anything online specific to macOS.

Comment: [Scoop](https://www.macosbytes.com/scoop.html)?

Comment: looks really cool, missed it in google searching, thank you.